# Kafka serialization difference between LongSerializer and Serdes.LongSerde

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We are writing a new application which publish to Kafka and we need to serialize the key of the messages as a long value. When checking the Kafka docs for serialization, seems there are two long serializer classes as LongSerializer and Serdes.LongSerde. We tried searching for a reference for the difference between the two but could not find any link explaining the difference. Appreciate if someone can please let us know / share a link which explains the difference between these. Or are these the same?

Primary link to Serializer Doc: https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/package-frame.html

LongSerializer: https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/LongSerializer.html

Serdes.LongSerde: https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serdes.LongSerde.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you should know, for Kafka (Brokers) messages are arrays of bytes (keys, values).

KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer and KafkaStreams need to know how to write and read messages - transform them from POJO to array of bytes and vice versa.

For that purpose `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer` and `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer` are used. KafkaProducer uses `Serializer` - to transform `Key` and `Value` to array of bytes, and KafkaConsumer uses `Deserializer` to transform array of bytes to `Key` and `Value`. 
KafkaStreams applications does both action writes, reads (to/from topic) and for that `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes` are - It is some kind of wrapper for `Serializer` and `Deserializer`.

**In your example**:

- `LongSerializer` is a class, that should be used to translate `Long` to array of bytes
- `LongSerde` is a class, that should be used in Kafka Streams application to read and write Long (under the hood it uses `LongSerializer` and `LongDeserializer`)

Additional reading:

- https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @wardziniak